# Which has more density: 100 °C steam or 100 °C dry air?

Tags: material-science, experimental-physics, steam

I am aware of the fact that steam is lighter than dry air. But I want to understand if it is merely because of the temperature difference.

Comment: steam has a RMM of 18, air is up around 29ish, so steam at the same temperature and pressure is less dense than dry air.

Comment: Check the tables of thermodynamic properties for steam and air.

Answer (score 3):

There's an air of 'lmgtfy' about this question...
Wolfram Alpha is a great resource for quickly finding information like this.

[image: 100c air density wolfram] [image: 100c steam density wolfram]

You can see that the steam is significantly less dense than the air, at the same 100C temperature and at atmospheric pressure.

The relative density is $\frac{0.5976}{0.9459}=0.63 $
You may notice that this is almost exactly the same as the relative molecular mass: $\frac{18.015}{28.96}=0.62 $

[image: air molecular mass wolfram] [image: steam molecular mass wolfram]

The ideal gas law $pV=nRT$ can be manipulated to give $d = pM/RT$ where $d$ is the density of the gas in g/L, $M$ is the molar mass of the gas in g/mol, $p$ is pressure of the gas in ATM and $R$ is the gas law constant.

So you can see how for ideal gasses, given a constant pressure and temperature, the density is related only to the Molecular Mass.

It's important to note that Steam **does not** behave as an ideal gas in many situations, but I thought this might help you to intuitively understand why the air is more dense than the steam - it simply has more atomic particles crammed into the same volume!

Comment: Tip: `&deg;` for °, `&Omega;`for Ω, `&mu;`, etc. for all Greek letters, `&pm;` for ±. Look up HTML entities for more.